# Prove $\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x-1}$ is continuous on (0,1)

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta

Use the epsilon-delta definition to prove that 
$$
\dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{x-1} 
$$

is continuous on the interval $(0,1)$. I've tried a lot but I just can't seem to see the first step. I don't want the answer just a hint to get me rolling. I know it should be continuous because I looked at the graph, but after
$$
|\dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{x-1} - \dfrac{\sqrt{x_0}}{x_0-1}| < \varepsilon
$$

I get stuck. I've attempted bringing everything to a common denominator. Subtracting the $x_0$ term to the other side, but to no avail. Any help appreciated

Comment: Have you tried multiplying by $\sqrt {x}+\sqrt {x_0}$ (top and bottom, effectively by $1$) to introduce the term $ |x-x_0|$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: 
\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x-1}-\frac{\sqrt{x_0}}{x_0-1}\right|&=
\left|\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x-1}+\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x_0-1}-\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x_0-1}-\frac{\sqrt{x_0}}{x_0-1}\right|\\
&\leq \left|\sqrt{x}\right|\left|\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{1}{x_0-1}\right|+\left|\frac{1}{x_0-1}\right|\left|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x_0}\right|.
\end{align*}